# Chamada pelo menu não entra na Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho esse menu na _Layout.cshtml

```
 @if (Response.Cookies["UserSession"]["UserRole"] == "Rh" || Response.Cookies["UserSession"]["UserRole"] == "Admin")
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> RH - Relatórios<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Financiamento de veículos", "ExcelFinancing", "FinancingReport")
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        }
```

O problema é que ao chamar esse item de menu, deveria parar no break dentro da Action na controller. Essa é a Action na controller controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExcelFinancing(DateTime dateFinancing)
{
     var t = 1 * 9;//Teste apenas, break aqui
     return null;
}
```

O que passa é que quando eu clico nesse item de Menu, me dá o erro do tipo 500, internal server error(tratado pelo .net). Como eu faço para entrar na controller, chamando pelo Menu?

OBS: Tenho uma outra view chamada Visualizar.cshtml que herda de _Layout.cshtml e nela tenho outras funções. Devo fazer algo a partir dela? Ou a chamada somente na _Layout.cshtml seria suficiente?

Comment: Cara, testei aqui e aparentemente está certo, única coisa que imaginei que poderia estar errado é o nome do seu controller pra não cair lá, ele está nomeado como FinancingReportController?

Comment: Montando um link não está passando o parâmetro "dateFinancing"

Comment: Faça um teste, tente remover o parâmetro "Datetime dateFinancing" da sua Action e veja se funciona.

Comment: @BrunoSoares, removi o parâmetro e agora pausou no break. Se responder, eu marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua action possui um parâmetro DateTime dateFinancing, porém no seu ActionLink você não está passando este parâmetro.

Ou remova o parâmetro da action, ou tenta algo como isso no seu link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Financiamento de veículos", "ExcelFinancing", "FinancingReport", new { dateFinancing = null })
```

Sendo que você deve substituir o null do parâmetro pela data que você quer passar por parâmetro.